# Regex - Select lines having more than one uppercase

Tags: php, regex

I have a text, something like:

```
1: hello people on stackoverflow, this here is my sample string
2: to show you what I want to achive. Here are some lines
3: I want to select
4: asdAsasDAqdVGevSerE312d1d14fF2Asdc
5: klhkblkljhb2k324JKgnqwwuUIH82mjkaw
6: heLloIsWhatIwantToSelectToo
7: thisLineshouldnotbeselected
8: butThislineshouldbeselectedasWell
9: and some more lines here...
```

Now I'm testing around since a few hours to get a regexp to select lines having more than 1 uppercased character and no whitespaces.

So I want to select line **4**, **5**, **6** and **8**.

All my tries match lines having 2 uppercased like **yXXy** but I want to select the line having them like **XyyX** or **XyXy**.

Is this possible with regulare expressions ?

Need them to be used in php later on...

Smaple RegExp im on atm:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9=]?(?! )){2,}$
```

I truely had more but since I'm stuck selecting like explained above... I dont have a clue what to write ^^

Comment: Show us your code attempts.

Comment: I posted a regexp that is currently open but this is not even close to the regexp im looking for. or at least the hint im looking for to solve the selection problem :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> a regexp to select lines having more than 1 uppercased character and no whitespaces.

You could use the following regular expression:

```
/^\S*[A-Z]\S*[A-Z]\S*$/
```

[**Example Here**](https://regex101.com/r/mM2dQ1/1)

- `^` - Anchor denoting the start of the line
- `\S*` - Zero or more non-white space characters
- `[A-Z]` - Uppercase character
- `\S*[A-Z]\S*` - Zero or more non-white space characters around a uppercase character
- `$` - Anchor denoting the end of the line

Adjust the flags accordingly. In the demo I am using the global and multi-line flags (but PHP doesn't have a `g` flag).

Comment: actually this is exactly what i was looking for!!! THX +1 and exapted as soon as I can

Comment: is it also possible to select a line having only small characters but a number as well ? reason: the content i want to select is over several lines and actually base64 code. since I run into problems selecting by length I decided to try a multiple uppercase select :) and may the last line is only 5 characters long but can have all small characters and mostly 1 or more digits

Comment: @Dwza `/^[a-z\d]+$/gm` for only lower case characters and digits. If you only want a single number, you could use `/^[a-z]*\d[a-z]*$/gm`.

Comment: Note the `g` modifier doesn't exist in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

```
^\S*[A-Z]\S*[A-Z]\S*$
```

- `^` start of string
- `\S*` zero or more non-whitespace characters
- `[A-Z]` uppercase character
- `$` end of string

Regex match in PHP: `preg_match("/^\S*[A-Z]\S*[A-Z]\S*$/", $text)`

Answer (score 1):

```
([a-z0-9]*[A-Z][a-z0-9]*[A-Z]\w*)
```

This seems to work based on http://regexr.com/

Basically I use *, which means optional with any ammount, so it could have from 0 to whatever number regex support of characters from a-z or 0-9, then I expect at least 1 upper case, followed again by 0 to infinite characters from a-z to 0-9, another uppercase, and then any non whitespace character.